# Vertical-align span inside div @ 100% height & fixed width on hover (example included)

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, vertical-alignment

I am trying to achieve a hidden element that is revealed on hover, over a div that the height is unknown.

A perfect example of this is here:

http://issuu.com/

If you scroll down and hover over any publication image, it will show a semi-transparent overlay with the words "read now" perfectly aligned centrally both vertically and horizontally. both fading in and out on and off hover.

I am trying to achieve exactly this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mr14wt5c/)

Here is my implementation using pure html and css:

HTML

```
<div class="content">
    Hello here is content.Hello here is content.Hello here is content.Hello here is content.Hello here is content.Hello here is content.Hello here is content.Hello here is content.Hello here is content.Hello here is content.Hello here is content.Hello here is content.Hello here is content.
    <div class="hiddenElement"></div>
    <div class="textElement">Read Now</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content{
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background:#ccc;
    position:relative;
}
.hiddenElement,.textElement{
     position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}
.hiddenElement{

    background:#fff;
    opacity:0.6;
}
.textElement{
    opacity:1;
    top:50%;
}
.content:hover .hiddenElement,.content:hover .textElement{
    display:block;
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, unfortunately this will not work as the height is fixed. so line-height will not work, the image width is 235px and height is in scaled according to width.

Comment: Hey James. Fiddle updated for dynamic height. Check it now.

Comment: See my answer. Removed line-height. It will now work for images with different height. And fiddle link in my answer is updated one.

Comment: This works really well, except I had to add a minus top margin on the text element to get the text perfectly central vertically due to the height of the text itself. Will just try and implement it and test it into my code.

Comment: If it solved your problem, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example using flexbox: http://jsfiddle.net/hj3gfwuk/

Your html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <p>Read now.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your css:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%
}

.child {
    display: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.parent:hover .child {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

**The basic idea:** The child element (the hidden element) has a height and width of 100% of the parent, and a background with some transparency to it. It is initially hidden with `display: none;` When you hover over the `.parent`, the css for `.child` is changed, and the element is displayed. Hope this helps!

Comment: Very simple and clean, could I ask how friendly is this method throughout all browsers?

Comment: Here's a great resource for this kind of question: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Thanks, will check it out, although I have just tried your fiddle, and I attempted to added an image behind the text overlay and cannot get it to work correct.

The image is fixed width of 235px, and the height of the image will be "auto" in relation to its width. but the overlay seems to stretch it.

Comment: updated fiddle addressing background issues. Note that this solution should work in IE11 and Edge: http://jsfiddle.net/hj3gfwuk/1/

Comment: this unfortunately uses images as background, the images need to be inline code as the images are pulled from database. also fixed width. perfect example on here issuu.com

Comment: I've just moved the css to be an inline-style and changed the width from a percentage to fixed pixels: http://jsfiddle.net/hj3gfwuk/3/

Comment: Works great except I wasn't as clear as I could have been sorry my fault, the images really need to be nested with a < img > and not as a background.

Answer (score 0):

@pgruber solution is not working in Internet explorer for me.
In @devendrant solution , he is fixing `line-height: 300px;` or in the question ther is `div that the height is unknown.`
try this demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bk88h6of/2/)

**html:**

```
<div class="content">
    <img src="http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg"/>
    <div class="overlay">
    <span>Read more</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
div.content{
    position:relative;
}
div.content:hover div.overlay{
    display:block;
}
div.overlay{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #000;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
div.overlay span{
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -9px;
    margin-left: -35px;
}
```

Comment: Hi not working unfortunately, the width of the image is actually fixed but the height is scaled according to width. so the hover overlay will be fixed width to the image and height at 100% of image behind.

Comment: you can try with different div's width and height, normally the result will be the same